# Advanced and Retarded Coordinates for Hawking Radiation

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, hawking-radiation

I am trying to solve the Klein Gordon equation near the horizon of a black hole. For a more accurate result I am using the Vaidya Metric in which the mass is a function of retarded time u.

When considering the black hole to have a stationary horizon, Hawking shifts his coordinates to the advanced and Retarded Coordinates. Since the Vaidya Metric is in the form of retarded coordinates, I was wondering whether I have to make the transformation again?

Also my concepts are not so clear regarding this, so it would be helpful if someone clears it.

Thanks in advance.